# Multilevel category showing for select options in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I am using grouped_options_for_select to show some category in my rails project. Code below

```
collection = ["North America",[["United States",["inner"]],["Canada",["inner"]]]]

<%= select_tag(::id_methods, grouped_options_for_select(collection, selected_key = " ", prompt = nil)) %>
```

This output as below

```
North America
United States inner
 Canada
 inner
```

But want the output as below

```
North America
 United Sates
  inner
 Canada
  inner
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
collection = ["North America",["United States",["inner"]],["Canada",["inner"]]]

<%= select_tag(:id_methods, grouped_options_for_select(collection, selected_key = " ", prompt = nil)) %>
```

Comment: This output two level category dropdownlist but I need three level category dropdownlist